# Distinct values in my table

Tags: sql, oracle

say I have a table with following column and records

```
NAME            RESULT   DATE
----------------------------------------------
John            Pass    12-FEB-2013 18:03:55
Albert          Fail    12-FEB-2013 18:24:29
Chris           Pass    12-FEB-2013 18:24:28
John            Fail    12-FEB-2013 19:32:35
Chris           Pass    12-FEB-2013 19:32:35
Steve           Pass    12-FEB-2013 20:04:35
```

now if I need distinct values from NAME column I did the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT(NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

now If I do the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT(NAME), 
       RESULT, 
       DATE 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4;
```

I get all the RECORDS in the names column. But I don't need all the records. I only need distinct names even with the above WHERE clause. Pls help me.

Comment: What if your `WHERE` clause returns tow rows with name 'John'?

Comment: @a_horse_with_noname 's first query helped me... Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is ***NOT*** a function. You simply added paranthesises to the *column name*. It's essentially the same as the difference between `select name, result ...` and `select (name), result ...`

It is an operator that works on the *complete* row. And because of that you get all rows because the combination of name, result, date is always different (btw. `date` is a horrible name for a column. Not only because it's a reserved word, but also because it doesn't *document* what's in the column. Is it a birthdate? A termination date? A start date? An end date? ...).

If you only want e.g the latest date for each name, you need a `group by`:

```
select name, 
       max(result) as result,
       max(trunc(date)) as dt
from table_name 
group by name;
```

Note that this does not necessarily return the result that belongs to the max date. If you need that, consider something like this:

```
select name, result, result_date
from (
    select name, 
           result,
           trunc(date) as result_date,
           row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as rn
    from table_name 
) t
where rn = 1;
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry "DATE" is just an example I used here. I use "RUN_DATE" as my actual column name. What I need is I want to display distinct NAME on 12th feb... If I do the second query in my original post it's displaying non-distinct names from 12th feb. I tried the below query and it gave me duplicate names SELECT DISTINCT NAME, DATE, RESULT FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4

And yes I need NAME, DATE, RESULT to be shown on my result as I'm using them in my Java program

Comment: I guess your first query helped me... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: when I do 
SELECT DISTINCT NAME,MAX(RESULT) AS RESULT, MAX(DATE) as RUN_DATE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TRUNC(DATE) < TRUNC(SYSDATE)-2 GROUP BY NAME;

The above query gives me the result. one of the record from above query is john --- pass --- 12-FEB-2013 18:03:55 ...... but lets say I only want the "fail" RESULT if a NAME has both "Pass" and "Fail"... how do I get that?

Comment: @user1629109 - You should probably have asked that as a new question, since it's quite a way from your original problem. But, you can just add `result` to the `order by` for the `row_number()` function in the second example. Also you don't need the `distinct` as well as the `group by` in what you just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing.  If you want to retrieve the `DISTINCT` names using your supplied `WHERE` criteria, just do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4;
```

If however you want the other fields with the date truncated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, RESULT, TRUNC(DATE) dt
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4;
```

Or, if you want the full time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, RESULT, DATE
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for confusing you. What I need is I want to display distinct NAME on 12th feb... If I do the second query in my original post it's displaying non-distinct names from 12th feb.

Comment: @user1629109 -- use my 2nd query without the RESULT column then: SELECT DISTINCT NAME, TRUNC(DATE) dt 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4;

Comment: It didn't work. I tried that. It's still giving me duplicate names.

Comment: Post what you tried -- SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4 will not return duplicate names unless the names are stored differently (with spaces for example) in the table...

Comment: you're correct. But I need all three columns and not just name. I need NAME, DATE, RESULT. that's the problem. so the below query did not work as it gave me duplicate names
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, DATE, RESULT FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TRUNC(DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4

Comment: Because DATE is unique -- use TRUNC(DATE) as in my 2nd query above -- best of luck!